# Mouseleave race condition

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, dom-events

I'm building a menu bar. In the bar every menu item contains a link, and those which have a submenu, have also a clickable area to open the submenu. The logic to show and hide submenus is done with JavaScript, it mainly toggles the class names of the elements by click and mouseleave events.

A mouseleave event has been attached to all the submenu elements, and a one to their opener elements. These events take care of hiding a submenu(s) when needed. A click listener has been attached to the element wrapping the entire menu bar. This listener opens a submenu when needed, or closes all the submenus, if a link was clicked.

The occurred problem is next: When user clicks on a link, all subs are hidden by switching their class to such which set `display: none`. Naturally this will fire mouseleave events, and the logic based on class toggling shows the submenus again.

I've tried to tackle the issue by setting a flag, which is checked in the mouseleave handlers. If the flag has been set, nothing is done. The flag will be reset after a short delay.

This works in FF and Chrome, but causes a weird problem in IE11 and Edge: If user keeps mouse still after clicking a link, and starts moving the mouse after the delay (500 msecs) has elapsed, the hidden submenus pop up to the screen again.

This seems to happen, because the mouseleave events are firing on a hidden elements, and even after a delay. How can I fix the code, so that IE and Edge could keep the submenus hidden too?

You can reproduce the issue with IE11 and Edge on the Stack Snippet below, or play with a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t1rxu1zc/).

```js
var WWMainMenu = {
    /// Hides all Submenus in Mainmenu
    closeAllSubs: function () {
        var subs = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.mainMenu.querySelectorAll('.ww-submenu-exp'));
        subs.forEach(function (sub) {
            sub.classList.toggle('ww-submenu');
            sub.classList.toggle('ww-submenu-exp');
            return;
        });
        return;
    },
    /// Hides a current Submenu when blurring the opener element
    closeCurrent: function (e) {
        var nextSub = e.target.nextElementSibling;
        if (this.noLeave) {
            return; /// Quit, toggling sub is not allowed
        }
        if (e.relatedTarget !== nextSub && nextSub.classList.contains('ww-submenu-exp')) {
            nextSub.classList.toggle('ww-submenu');
            nextSub.classList.toggle('ww-submenu-exp');
        }
        return;
    },
    /// Shows/hides Submenu
    toggleSubmenu: function (e) {
        var target = e.target,
            that = this;
        /// Hide all Submenus when clicking on links
        if (target.tagName === 'A') {
         this.closeAllSubs();
            // Circumvent the race condition
            this.noLeave = true;
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                that.noLeave = false;
            }, 500);
            return;
        }
        /// Validate the target
        if (!target.classList.contains('ww-menuentry')) {
            return;
        } /// Quit, not clicked on a menuentry
        /// Toggle the visibility of Submenu
        target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('ww-submenu');
        target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('ww-submenu-exp');
        return;
    },
    /// Hides Submenu when blurring the menu itself
    hideSubmenu: function (e) {
        if (this.noLeave) {
            return; /// Quit, toggling sub is not allowed
        } 
        if (this.mainMenu.classList.contains('ww-show-menu')) {
            return; /// Quit, no autoclose when on small screens
        } 
        e.target.classList.toggle('ww-submenu');
        e.target.classList.toggle('ww-submenu-exp');
        return;
    },
    /// Initializes a WWMainmenu object
    init: function (options) {
        var subs, /// Stores all Submenu elements in Mainmenu [Array]
            entries; /// Stores all Menuentry elements in Mainmenu [Array]
        subs = Array.prototype.slice.call(options.menuBar.querySelectorAll('.ww-submenu'));
        entries = Array.prototype.slice.call(options.menuBar.querySelectorAll('.ww-menuentry'));
        /// Create prooperties
        this.mainMenu = options.menuBar; /// Reference to the Mainmenu element [HTMLElement]
        this.noLeave = false; /// Flag controlling mouseleave handling on Submenus and Menuentries
        /// Add click listener for toggling Submenus
        this.mainMenu.addEventListener('click', this.toggleSubmenu.bind(this));
        /// Add blur listeners for Submenus
        subs.forEach(function (sub) {
            sub.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.hideSubmenu.bind(this));
            return;
        }, this);
        /// Add blur listeners for Menuentries
        entries.forEach(function (entry) {
            entry.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.closeCurrent.bind(this));
            return;
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
}.init({
 menuBar: document.querySelector('.ww-mainmenu-bar')
});
```

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* Menu system */
.ww-mainmenu-bar {
 display: block;
 background-color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1);
 font-size: 1.0em;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.ww-mainmenu {
 display: inline-block;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.ww-menuentry, .ww-menuentry a, .ww-submenu-exp a {
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.ww-menuentry {
 padding: 5px;
}
.ww-menuentry:hover {
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
 background: rgba(70, 130, 180, 1);
}
.ww-menuentry::after {
 content: "\2261";
 position: absolute;
 right: 10px;
 cursor: default;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.ww-mainmenu > .ww-menuentry::after {
 position: relative;
 content: "\2261";
 right: 0px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); 
}
.ww-submenu, .ww-submenu-exp {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 min-width: calc(160px);
 background: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1);
 font-size: 0.95em;
 z-index: 20;
 white-space: nowrap;
 margin-left: 2em;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.ww-submenu-exp {
 display: block;
}
.ww-submenu-exp > a {
 display: block;
 padding: 5px;
}
.ww-submenu-exp > a:hover {
 background: rgba(70, 130, 180, 1);
}
```

```html
<!-- MAIN MENU -->
<nav class="ww-mainmenu-bar">
    <div class="ww-mainmenu">
        <div class="ww-menuentry"><a href="#">Main link</a></div>
        <div class="ww-submenu">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <div class="ww-menuentry"><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
            <div class="ww-submenu">
                <a href="#">Link 2.1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2.2</a>
            </div>     
            <div class="ww-menuentry"><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
            <div class="ww-submenu">
                <a href="#">Link 3.1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3.2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I using a JS framework and getting done with it in probably a few lines of code out of the question ...? Also, I would start by refactoring the HTML, into what is considered a proper navigation structure these days, namely nested UL/LI.

Comment: @CBroe I'm sure you know, what there is under the hood of frameworks, just even more code, and the most of it being not useful. What comes to list, the code is at early state. I just didn't want to struggle with the margins and all that extra CSS what is needed with lists, yet. Any suggestions to the problem at hands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `hideSubmenu` function, why don't you explicitly call `hide()` instead of `toggle()` ?

Comment: Well, in the real code I've single toggle calls like `ui.toggleClass(e.target, 'ww-submenu ww-submenu-exp');`, which switces the classes. The entire code is based on switching classes, `ww-submenu` sets `display:none`, `ww-submenu-exp` sets `display: block`. I'd like to preserve the principal.

Comment: When you are switching or toggling, you always have the possibility that the correct value is already set, and you are switching it incorrectly.  Can you use removeClass("ww-submenu-exp") and addClass("ww-submenu")?   Or check to see which one is present, and if alreadycorrect, then don't toggle? It just seems like in a function named hideSubmenu, you should want it to go only one direction -- not actually toggle.

Comment: Though your answer doesn't directly answer the question, it led me to the correct solution, i.e. to check in close handlers, whether the target has `ww-submenu-exp` class or not. Thanks for the tip. My question now looks quite stupid because of the easy solution, maybe I should sleep more ...

Comment: @Alan Doesn't [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) take a second parameter to force it one way or the other?

Comment: @Zev  `toggle()` changes visible elements to hidden, and hidden elements to visible. It depends entirely on the current state. There is a parameter for a function to run after the animation is complete, and that function could do anything you wanted. So you could toggle a visible element (make it hidden), then the function could make it visible again.

Comment: I think you are confusing between the jQuery [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), which behaves as you describe; and the DOM `classList` object's [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) method. The OP doesn't appear to be using jQuery, and in every place he's using toggle, it's as a method on `classList`; it makes sense that he means the DOM `toggle`. Note also, that one of the overloads of jQuery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) takes a single boolean; it will also force show/hide accordingly.